# String Literal Types (like in TypeScript) in Dart?

Tags: typescript, dart

I started using Dart thanks to Flutter and I quite like the language.

I was using TypeScript before which offered some really cool features that I hadn't seen before, one I particularly liked is the [string literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) that look something like this

```
type Easing = "ease-in" | "ease-out" | "ease-in-out";
function doSomething(easing: Easing) { /* do something */}
doSomething("ease-in");  // OK
doSomething("easy");  // ERROR
```

In Dart, I find using `enum`s sometimes inconvenient, especially when interacting with platform-specific implementations of plugins. I miss string literal types every time I need to add a Dart interface for Android's `static String`s or `enum`s.

One [example](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/android_intent/example/lib/main.dart) of this would be from the [`android_intent`](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/android_intent) plugin (but happens much more often):

```
void _createAlarm() {
  final AndroidIntent intent = const AndroidIntent(
    action: 'android.intent.action.SET_ALARM',
    arguments: <String, dynamic>{
      'android.intent.extra.alarm.DAYS': <int>[2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
      'android.intent.extra.alarm.HOUR': 21,
      'android.intent.extra.alarm.MINUTES': 30,
      'android.intent.extra.alarm.SKIP_UI': true,
      'android.intent.extra.alarm.MESSAGE': 'Create a Flutter app',
    },
  );
  intent.launch();
}
```

**Is there a way in Dart to have these "magic strings" like in TypeScript's string literal types?**

Answer (score 2):

Dart `enum` constants have a [`name`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/EnumName.html) extension that returns a string with the name of the constant.  For example, given:

```dart
enum MyEnum {
  myConstant,
}
```

then `MyEnum.myConstant.name` will return `'myConstant'`.  Although this won't let you easily create arbitrary strings, you could do something like:

```dart
enum Alarm {
  DAYS,
  HOUR,
  MINUTES,
  SKIP_UI,
  MESSAGE,
}

void _createAlarm() {
  final arguments = <Alarm, dynamic>{
    Alarm.DAYS: <int>[2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    Alarm.HOUR: 21,
    Alarm.MINUTES: 30,
    Alarm.SKIP_UI: true,
    Alarm.MESSAGE: 'Create a Flutter app',
  };
    
  final AndroidIntent intent = const AndroidIntent(
    action: 'android.intent.action.SET_ALARM',
    arguments: {
      for (var MapEntry(:key, :value) in arguments.entries)
        'android.intent.extra.alarm.${key.name}': value,
    },
  );

  intent.launch();
}
```

Comment: You can use `name` instead of `toString()`. It'll return "myConstant" in your example. Also, you can create an extension on the Enum to return specific String with your special symbols as you want like ```extension GetEnumName on Alarm {
switch(this){
case Alarm.SKIP_UI: return "SKIP-UI something that cannot be a variable name";

}
}```

Comment: @MostafaAlazhariy Thanks for reminding me to update this answer, which was written before extension methods (including `name` for `Enum`s) were added.