# String literal type analogue in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I know that in Dart there's no string literal types like:

```
interface IButtonProps {
 readonly variant: 'primary' | 'secondary'
 readonly size: 'small' | 'regular' | 'big' | 'a little bigger than usually'
}

const Button:FC<IButtonProps> = ({variant, size}) => {
 // ...
}
```

But what are my choises if i really want that button to accept only primary/secondary variants and suggest variants to me/my team/the community if i'm writing a library ?

I know i can assert props but there would not be any suggestions in editor only error at compile time.
So is there anything i can do to get that functionality ? Something like creating a ButtonVariants class and accepting only its fields / creating enum / list / set / whatever or i dont know...

I really need that strict typing in any form and not to create one hell of a widgets like PrimaryButton SecondaryButton SmallPrimaryButton...

Note that this stupid primary/secondary is just an example.

Comment: Um, can you use a enumerator like "ButtonVariant" that will have 2 values?

Comment: Some example code please ?

I need to create something like: 


class Button extends StatelessWidget {

 final Something variant; // Something is accepting primary | secondary
 
const Button(this.variant = ''primary" /* or ButtonVariants.primary or something*/); 
//...
}

and then

Button(variant: 'primary' /*Or ButtonVariants.primary, editor must suggest here*/);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use enumarators like this

```dart
enum ButtonType { primary, secondary }
enum ButtonSize { small, regular, big }

class Button {
  final ButtonType type;
  final ButtonSize size;

  AbstractButton(this.type, this.size);
}
```

Extend your class from widget class if you're using flutter

Comment: Oh nice, thank you ) 
i've seen this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/55625568/11815848 but did not understand how to apply this in my case.