# Dart - How to set a variable as a type String of being a few specific options?

Tags: dart, types

I'm trying to set a variable as a String of being a few specific options. I'm writing or converting it from TypeScript and am trying to reproduce this:

```
let myVar: 'a' | 'b' | 'c';
```

```
String myVar;
```

... is as far as I can get.

How can I write this in Dart, please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String literal type analogue in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58578837/string-literal-type-analogue-in-dart)

Comment: another useful [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59309104/1891712)